# Is there a way to Create CodeSpace using CLI or API

Tags: github, codespaces

For now I can able to create CodeSpace using option available in GitHub UI as shown in the below screenshot.

[Create CodeSpace Option](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nTE2m.png)

Is there any option to automate the CodeSpace creation flow like CLI (or) API, from which I can create CodeSpace?

Answer (score 1):

You can create Codespaces via both the CLI and API:

- https://cli.github.com/manual/gh_codespace_create
- https://docs.github.com/en/rest/reference/codespaces#create-a-codespace-for-the-authenticated-user